# Redirect permanent, www redirect & url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

I gave an old website a new CMS. Now i need a .htaccess with 3 parts, but it only works with 2 of them:

1. Redirect permanent
2. www redirect (this don't work)
3. url rewriting

Now i 'll explain something more.
Part 0 (only for the totality)

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Part 1 (Redirect permanent) i use to redirect the URLs of the old CMS to the content of the new one.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/de-old-content.html
Redirect permanent /de-old-content.html /old/content.html
```

Part 2 (www redirect) i use to avoid duplicate content.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Part 3 (url rewriting) to convert "old/content.html" into "index.php?adresse=old/content"

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?adresse=$1 [l,qsa]
```

the [l,qsa] only allows to use $_GET.

Is it possible to combine this parts?

If i use Part 2 it shows the right content with

http://www.website.de/abc/def/ghi.html

but without www it redirect to

http://www.website.deabc/

I think there must be a misstake in this Part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it redirect to the wrong host? Note that the **Redirect** directive does not work with the RewriteCond condition, they're part of different modules.

Comment: Please use URLs for the examples, not rules. They are not working in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect is part of mod_alias, while RewriteCond and RewriteRule are part of mod_rewrite. As a consequence the RewriteCond of part 1 accually applies to the RewriteRule of part 2, which would make it not work properly.

Best to avoid using both rewriterule and redirect together.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^de-old-content\.html$ /old/content.html [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?adresse=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PS. to keep your sanity, use 302's while testing. Once everything is working, change them to 301's. Since you already used 301's, also clear your browser cache, so all the old 301's are removed from the browser's cache.